# How to add click function to image?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm working on an application in it consists of of searchbar which is a image and that image needs to have a click function. I am new to ionic so can anyone help me with this.

Comment: You should paste some code of at least what you tried so far, you will get more answers like that. I recommend you edit your answer and add some more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer will give you brief Idea, How you can do your requirement

```
<img src="" alt="" (click)="doSomething()">
```

and in the `component.ts` file

```
doSomething()
{
 // do whatever you want  here
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me the code for linking the page to the image in ionic 4. Suppose when i click on the image it should be able to open the new page

Comment: then create component and make routing for that in the routing.ts and then here `this.router.navigate(['/route'])`